# Calling Snowflake stored procedure from Go driver

Tags: sql, go, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stored procedure in Snowflake called SP_MERGE_ASSETS. I can call it from the Snowflake console by doing this:

```
CALL MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.sp_merge_assets(0)
```

This works and does exactly what I expect it to. However, when I try the exact same procedure from Snowflake's Go library:

```
query := "CALL MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.sp_merge_assets(?)"
_, err := client.db.ExecContext(ctx, query, 0)
```

I get an SQL compilation error stating, `Unknown user-defined function MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.SP_MERGE_ASSETS`.

I suppose this makes sense as there isn't a UDF named "MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.SP_MERGE_ASSETS" defined in my account. But this error masks the actual problem: my stored procedure isn't being called. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is an error so it definitely reach Snowflake. What is the actual query: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, unlike in SQL server, calling a stored procedure in Snowflake requires using the `QueryContext` function instead of the `ExecContext` function. If you use `ExecContext`, Snwoflake will interpret the query as a call to a user-defined function. Changing the code to

```
query := "CALL MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.sp_merge_assets(?)"
_, err := client.db.QueryContext(ctx, query, 0)
```

fixed the issue.